# Consistent vertical alignment of self-made font

Tags: fonts, font-design

I have created a custom font using Font Studio.

However, at certain zooms in Excel the letters of the font do not align correctly.  Here is the font at 160 % zoom:

[image]

And here is the font at 115 % zoom:

[image]

As you can see, the "n" is slightly taller than the "o" at 115 % but they are the same height at 160 %.

For comparison, here is what it looks like when I use Calibri at 115 %:
[image]

Comment: The reason it varies by zoom factor is that it is basically  a rounding error (see: quantization error) where the vector line (i.e. a real number) would fall between pixels (i.e. integers) and the renderer has to decide which pixel to use. Hinting (as wrslprmft suggests) is baking in an expert opinion for the renderer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is *[hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinting),* in particular *blue values.* The latter define certain horizontal bands corresponding to important vertical lines, such as the baseline, the midline, the cap height and so on. At small font sizes, the font renderer then aligns all the glyphs’ vertical lines that fall into those bands on the same height. For example the top of the *n* and the *o* should fall into one of such bands corresponding to the midline.

It may suffice to use an auto-hinter for this, either one implemented in your font creator or an independent one like [TTFAutohint](http://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/).